# Provider is not valid

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2016

The below code is producing an error by saying `{"Keyword not supported: 'provider'."}` I can't update my database table.

`con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Comp-296\Project1\Project1\Game_time.mdb"`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the SqlClient library , try OleDB instead:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
con.ConnectionString = "yourconstring"
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll I got this error did I do something wrong.

Comment: Try
            con.Open()

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("INSERT INTO User_Scores VALUES('" & _
                                       txtUser.Text & "','" & _
                                       txtGame.Text & "',' " & _
                                       txtScore.Text & "')"), con)
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error while inserting record on table...", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
        Me.Validate()

Comment: well that is a different error, I assume the suggestion above worked. if so, please mark as answered.the error you are getting now seems like its related to a  the parameters you are including.. so make sure you have values for those.. also add a try/catch block to these so your errors are handled

Comment: I got a new error: it's saying The Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is not reigistered on the local machine.

Comment: what version of access is this mdb created in. 2000, 2003, 07, 10 ?

Comment: The access i have is 2016

Comment: try this in your provider, instead of Microsoft Jet: Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0   in addition, if this is a web application, then what matters is the provider installed on the server and not your machine

Comment: Using windows form to put data in the dataGrid i dont know how to change it. I used the this code instead:   Try
            Me.User_scoresTableAdapter1.Insert(CStr(txtUser.Text), CStr(txtGame.Text), CDec(txtScore.Text), CDate(txtDate.Text))
            Me.User_scoresTableAdapter1.Fill(Game_timeDataSet2._User_scores)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Data Input Error")
        End Try